# Chart.js - Incorrectly spaced labels on X Axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am looking to delete this .95 X axis label and move the bubble that goes there in between 90 and 100 like the graph on the right. When I just delete the .95 from labels I get the bubbles stacked on each other. I want to show .5-1 but I want the bubble to plot on .95 still.

labels: [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1],
[image: Want to delete .95 label on x axis to have it look better]

This is what happens when I just remove the .95 from labels. The chart appears how I want it but my bubbles are stacking on the 1 instead of between .9 and 1.

[image: This is what happens when I just delete .95 from the labels]

Comment: In order to do this .. You're going to have to make ALL labeled plots with a `.5`  -- Graphs are intended to be *uniform*,  and as such the algorithm that builds that graph out is *rounding* your plot point up, or down accordingly.  So 95 becomes 100.  You'll need 55-65-75-85-95 as labeled plot points ..

Comment: @Zak that worked, I just had to deconstruct my data series to explicitly label the x values. From data = bcc_results.curve_series to x: .5, y: bcc_results.curve_series[0], etc